# Is there a way of rotating the JW Player in CSS or Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jwplayer

I'm using a JW Player and currently I stream there a video through rtmp protocol. The code looks like this:

```
<div id="mediaspace2" >This text will be replaced</div></div>
<script>
jwplayer("mediaspace2").setup({
    flashplayer: "jwplayer.flash.swf",
    file: "rtmp://192.168.1.146:1935/live/myStream",
    height: 270,
    width: 480,
    skin: {
    name:'skins/JW-SKIN-ROUNDSTER.css'
    }

});
</script>
```

After doing so, the result on the webpage looks correct:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOGAa.png

But now I want to display it vertically, let's call it a portrait mode. So I added the simple div and modified its css:

```
<div id="rotated" style="  -moz-transform:translate(-95px,95px) rotate(270deg);
  -webkit-transform:translate(-95px,95px) rotate(270deg);
  -o-transform: translate(-95px,95px) rotate(270deg);
  -ms-transform:translate(-95px,95px) rotate(270deg);
  transform:translate(-95px,95px) rotate(270deg);">
<div id="mediaspace2" >This text will be replaced</div></div>
<script>
jwplayer("mediaspace2").setup({
    flashplayer: "jwplayer.flash.swf",
    file: "rtmp://192.168.1.146:1935/live/myStream",
    height: 270,
    width: 480,
    skin: {
    name:'skins/JW-SKIN-ROUNDSTER.css'
    }

});
</script>
```

and now the component is rotated, but the video is shrinked: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGsSs.png

Is there any way of fixing it?

Comment: Your video has a aspect ratio of 16:9. If you decrease the size of your 480px width to 270px and increase your height of 270px to 480px, then there's basically only 2 ways your video will be displayed. If you keep the aspect ratio of 16:9, then the video shrinks. If you stretch the video to 270x480, it'll be distorted. http://www.rtings.com/tv/learn/what-is-the-aspect-ratio-4-3-16-9-21-9?uxtv=ec5c

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this before, but what if you change the height and width of your player to width: 480 and height: 270? You might also need to play with the stretching options. Please see http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1413113-configuration-options-reference for more details on the stretching parameter.

We love Stack Overflow, but we don't check for new items here very often. The best way to get support for JW Player is from http://jwplayer.com/support/